# Variable with the exact name of the component in the scope

Tags: reactjs

Just started learning React from zero, regarding components ( when we define them with Uppercase letter), the tutorial is saying

> there must be a variable in the scope with that exact name.

I don't understand that and I don't SEE it from the examples of this tutorial.

Here he has:

```
function MyComponent() {
  var data = "world";
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <h2>{data}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Capital Letter. Got it. OK. then we can use it like:

```
<div>
  <div> Greetings </div>
  <MyComponent />
</div>
```

So from that example I can't see and understand what is he talking about. Can someone explain it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's talking about what happens behind the scenes.

Your react code you'll be transpiled by babel, and it'll call `React.createElelement` function. that's why you need to import React.

Remember `MyComponent` is a function variable after all. `React.createElelement` calls that function behind the scenes. To be able to call `MyComponent` (it's when you do `<MyComponent />`), `MyComponent` must exists in the first place in the scope where you do `<MyComponent />`. Meaning, either you have created `MyComponent` in that scope, or you've imported that variable (as `import MyComponent from './<path>/MyComponent'`) to that scope.

Comment: oh I see. Thanks for explanation.